# How to install Kafka as a service in ubuntu machine?

Tags: apache-kafka

I created  kafka cluster with two broker and one zookeeper. Every time I have to go to command line to start it. Can I install kafka cluster as a service in ubuntu?.How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add Kafka as a service in Ubuntu using *[systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)* and *[systemctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html)*. Look at this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units
It should be pretty straightforward and easy to setup any program (even something custom) as a service.